# Gehen, fahren -> Passivfähig?

Tags: passive

Ich möchte mal wissen, ob es eine Erklärung dafür gibt, weshalb **gehen** nicht passivfähig, wohingegen **fahren** passivfähig sein soll. In einer Übung meines Buches (Grammatik aktiv b2/c1) steht nämlich, dass **gehen** nicht unter den mit einem aktiven Subjekt versehenen Verben steht (was es passivunfähig machen würde); sollte das allerdings auch nicht für **fahren** gelten? Wieso hat **gehen** kein aktives Subjekt aber **fahren** doch?

Im Buch erwähnte Beispiele des unpersönlichen Passiv mit **fahren**:

> Auf dem Land wird häufig mit dem Auto gefahren.
>
> Es wird zum Wintersport in die Alpen gefahren.

Comment: Falls *ich* gegangen wurde, dann wurde ich rausgeworfen - ob das Passiv o.ä. ist, übersteigt meine Grammatikkenntnisse. Es ist mehr eine Redewendung.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Frage, was sich die Autoren des Buches gedacht haben, läßt sich nicht beantworten. Passivierte Formen von *gehen* findet man leicht. Natürlich muß man zunächst einmal transitives *gehen* ausschließen:

> Es ging einzig darum, welcher Weg gegangen wurde.

Ebenso die scherzhafte Wendung *gegangen werden* für *entlassen werden*, die es in den Duden geschafft hat: [6b](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gehen).

Ein paar Treffer für *gehen* im Wortsinne:

> Eine Theorie besagt, dass links geritten und gegangen wurde […] [1](https://www.freiepresse.de/ratgeber/onkel-max/warum-fahren-in-vielen-rechtsverkehr-laendern-die-zuege-links-artikel10712373)
>
> Vorbei sind einfach die Zeiten, in denen ausschließlich mit Anzug und Krawatte ins Büro gegangen wurde. [2](https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/panorama/Jogginghose-Sneaker-bunte-Socken-Die-Mode-der-Zehnerjahre-id56282886.html)
>
> Jeder der 14 einheimischen Bergführer hatte zwei Personen zu betreuen, achtete auf deren körperlichen Zustand und [darauf] dass nur langsam gegangen wurde. [3](https://www.zak.de/Nachrichten/Symbolischer-Sieg-gegen-die-Krankheit-Yunus-bezwingt-mit-der-Familie-den-Kilimandscharo-139104.html)
>
> Nach einem gemeinsamen Segens-Lied war der offizielle Teil des Mitarbeiterfestes vorüber, gegangen wurde aber noch lange nicht. [4](https://www.schwarzwaelder-bote.de/inhalt.dunningen-gelegenheit-zur-werbung-genutzt.0a9c0953-acd1-41c7-a2f6-683ae9ebe63a.html)

Für *gehen* in Wendungen:

> für die erste Sendung wurde auf Nummer sicher gegangen […]  [5](https://www.qiez.de/klaas-heufer-umlauf-joko-und-klaas-late-night-show/)
>
> auch wenn durchaus mit einer gewissen Körperlichkeit zur Sache gegangen wurde. [6](https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/friedberg/sport/Gersthofen-darf-in-Friedberg-jubeln-id56380391.html)
>
> Die Intensität, mit der in dieser Woche im Training zu Werke gegangen wurde […] [7](https://www.giessener-allgemeine.de/sport/lokalsport/gewarnt-vollgetankt-13108216.html)
>
> woraufhin der Ursache auf den Grund gegangen wurde. *(mit Dativobjekt)* [8](https://www.kosmo.at/falsches-medikament-verwandelt-babys-in-werwoelfe/)

Comment: Meine Güte, Sätze wie diese wären mir nie eingefallen :D Sehr interessant. Danke.

Answer (score 4):

Dass man selbst zwar gefahren werden kann, aber nicht gegangen werden kann, wurde in der ersten Antwort bereits erklärt.

Allerdings passen die Beispiele in der Frage nicht zu dieser Art der Passivform. Das was in der Frage mit *fahren* gezeigt wird, ist mit *gehen* durchaus auch möglich. Ich beziehe diese Antwort also im Zweifelsfall auf die Beispiele der Frage, nicht auf den sonstigen Text der Frage.
Es gibt nämlich schon eine Passivform für *gehen*, die zu den Zitaten aus der Frage passen.

Der Satz

> Am Sonntag wird bei uns in die Kirche gegangen.

drückt aus dass eine Gruppe von Personen üblicherweise sonntags in die Kirche geht. Die Formulierung "es wird..." drückt hier aus dass etwas schon immer so war und es auch weiterhin so sein soll bzw. wird.

Ich kenne diese Art der Formulierung vor allem um etwas zu fordern, oder etwas als selbstverständlich und ohne weitere Diskussion hinzunehmen.
Zum Beispiel wenn man einem Kind zum tausendsten mal erklärt warum es mit in die Kirche soll:

> Am Sonntag wird in die Kirche gegangen, da gibt es keine Diskussion.

Bedeutet: Wir gehen am Sonntag **immer** in die Kirche, also gehen wir auch heute wieder. Das ist so, also frag nicht schon wieder warum wir das tun.

Ein anderes Beispiel.

> Bei schönem Wetter wird hier viel spazieren gegangen

beschreibt, dass "hier" (d.h. in dieser Umgebung) bei schönem Wetter viele Menschen spazieren gehen.

Diese Formulierungen klingen nicht alltäglich, sind aber nicht falsch. Auch wenn man sie nicht oft hört, kommen sie durchaus zum Einsatz.

Comment: Ach so, man kann also das sagen? Dann hältst du die Behauptung der Übung im Buch (zumindest ohne Weiteres) für falsch, oder? Die lautet nämlich: "Hat das Verb ein aktives Subjekt? Ist Passiv möglich? Kreuzen Sie an." Und im Lösungsschlüssel steht das Verb "gehen" nicht angekreuzt.

Comment: @Beneficium Ist nicht sehr üblich, aber kommt vor. Vielleicht ist es auch regional begrenzt. Ich weiß nicht was mit "aktives Subjekt" gemeint ist. Bist du sicher dass deine Beispiele ein aktives Subjekt haben?

Comment: Canoo "definiert" es folgenderweise: "Nicht passivfähig sind dementsprechend Verben, die kein aktives Subjekt haben, deren Subjekt nicht der eigentliche Träger oder Verursacher der Handlung ist (= intransitive Vorgangs- oder Zustandsverben)." (url: https://cutt.ly/mrRqYrZ). Weder "gehen" noch "fahren" werden als Beispiele genannt.  Ich weiß ehrlich gesagt nicht genau, inwiefern meine Beispiele ein aktives Subjekt haben, aber, da sie im Passiv sind, nehme ich an, dass die Antwort sollte "ja" lauten.

Comment: Im Fall von *gehen* und *fahren* ist das Subjekt zweifellos Träger der Handlung, also gibt es ein aktives Subjekt. Gegenbeispiele wären die Verben *sein* und *werden*. In der Tat sagt man nicht "Es wird gewesen" oder "Es wird geworden". Dass diese Verben kein aktives Subjekt haben, wäre also die Begründung dafür.

Comment: @RHa Dann bist du auch der Meinung, dass "gehen" im Passiv stehen kann? Oder glaubst du, dass trotz des aktiven Subjekts das Verb nicht passivfähig sei?

Comment: *Gehen* kann genauso im unpersönlichen Passiv verwendet werden wie *fahren*. Hier ein Beispiel: https://www.spiegel.de/gesundheit/ernaehrung/schrittzaehler-studie-wo-viel-gegangen-wird-gibt-s-weniger-dicke-a-1157066.html

Answer (score 3):

Ich weiß nicht genau, was du mit aktivem und passivem Subjekt meinst.

*Gehen* kann (im Sinne von »Ich gehe ins Kino«) **nicht** im Passiv stehen, weil man nicht *von einer anderen Person gegangen werden* kann.
(Die Wendung »Er wurde gegangen« (ihm wurde gekündigt oder eine Position wurde ihm so ungemütlich gemacht, dass er von selbst gekündigt hat) ist umgangssprachlich und salopp.)

> Ich wurde ins Kino gegangen

ergibt keinen Sinn (ohne sehr kontextabhängig zu werden).

Für *fahren* gilt das nicht, denn neben »Ich fahre Auto« oder »Ich fahre ins Kino« gibt es noch die Form *jemanden (irgendwohin) fahren*.
Hier ist das Passiv problemlos **möglich**.

> Ich fahre meinen Kumpel zum Kino.
>   Mein Kumpel wird von mir zum Kino gefahren.

oder:

> Ich fahre Auto.
>   Das Auto wird von mir gefahren.

Deine Frage:

> Wieso hat gehen kein aktives Subjekt aber fahren doch?

Ich kenne diese Terminologie nicht, aber ich vermute, dass Folgendes gemeint ist:
Im Satz »Ich gehe ins Kino« ist das Subjekt (Ich) handelnd.
Es geht ins Kino.

Im Satz »Ich werde [von jemandem] zum Kino gefahren« ist das grammatische Subjekt (Ich) nicht selbst handelnd:
Es fährt nicht selbst.
Die eigentliche Handlung (das Fahren) erledigt jemand anders.
Diese andere Person kann mit einer Präposition in den Satz eingefügt werden, aber der Satz funktioniert auch ohne ihre explizite Erwähnung.

Comment: Ich stimme deiner Antwort völlig zu; Allerdings sind die im Buch erwähnten Beispiele mit "fahren" intransitiv: auf dem Land wird häufig mit dem Auto gefahren; Es wird zum Wintersport in die Alpen gefahren etc. Das sind zwar unpersönliche Passivsätze, aber nichtsdestoweniger sind sie doch im Passiv. Für diese Beispiele ist deine Erklärung nicht gültig, außer ich irre mich.

Comment: @Beneficium Du irrst Dich. Wie Phillip sehr schön erklärt hat ist _gehen_ implizit aktiv: _"weil man nicht von einer anderen Person gegangen werden kann."_ Für gehen macht es einfach keinen Sinn. Man braucht einen Körper und Beine um zu _gehen_. Das dieser Körper dies selbstständig tut ist implizit (wie man Roboter und Drohnen zu betrachten hätte ist eine andere Frage).

Comment: @Beneficium _"Es wird zum Wintersport in die Alpen gefahren"_ _Es wird zum Wintersport in die Alpen gegangen._  Hmm, letzteres wäre tatsächlich grammatikalisch korrekt (wenn auch unpersönlich _es wird_), aber doch zumindest sehr unüblich.

Comment: Ich bin zwar kein Muttersprachler, aber ein Satz wie "Wenn man kein Auto hat wird gegangen/gelaufen." klingt in meinen Ohren nicht allzu verkehrt.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ach so, also ihr meint, dass, da man **im Prinzip** gefahren werden kann (einerlei, ob man im konkreten vorliegenden Satz selbst fährt oder gefahren wird), der Satz passivfähig ist, wohingegen bei "gehen" man selbst im Prinzip nicht gegangen werden kann, weshalb der Satz immer passivunfähig ist. Verstehe ich das richtig?

Comment: @jarnbjo Das ist _Infinitiv_ nicht _Passiv_.

Comment: @Beneficium _"Verstehe ich das richtig?"_ Ich denke mal ja,

Comment: Da es im Deutschen ein unpersönliches Passiv gibt und in der Frage nach einer Unterscheidung zwischen Subjekten gefragt wurde, wundere ich mich, daß in der Antwort und in den Kommentaren über Objekte gesprochen wird.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Wenn jemand so betrunken ist, dass er aus eigener Kraft kaum noch stehen und gar nicht mehr (zielgerichtet) gehen kann, dann kann man aber durchaus sagen, dass er *zur Ausnüchterungszelle gegangen wird*, analog ein mit Handschellen gefesselter Verhafteter, der vergeblich versucht, nicht aufs Revier gegangen zu werden. Das funktioniert nicht nur grammatikalisch, das ergibt auch durchaus Sinn, der verstanden wird, auch wenn es eher humorvoll-salopp formuliert ist und man **hochsprachlich** und in **Schriftform** eher *abgeführt werden* bzw. *geleitet werden* verwenden würde.

Comment: @DavidVogt Das Problem liegt glaube ich darin, dass es bei meiner Frage ums intransitive "fahren" geht, wohingegen die meisten Antworten sich auf das transitive "fahren" beziehen. Für mich sind das Verben, die unterschiedlich zu behandeln sind, aber ich bin mir ehrlich gesagt nicht sicher.

Comment: @Beneficium Das Problem liegt m.E. in Deinem Verständnis von _gehen_ und nicht von _fahren_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ vielleicht hast du Recht. xD Ich muss mir noch ein bisschen überlegen, bis der Groschen endlich fällt. Ich bin sehr dankbar für die Antworten.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Nein, "wird gegangen" ist kein Infinitiv (das wäre "gehen").